# All the Application are gone from the Dash Home

Tags: installation

I am using an ubuntu 12.04 LTS in an EeePc netbook. I've been using this for more or less 3 months now. I keep on receiving a software update and install it without re-starting my netbook after the installation. Then suddenly, starting two weeks ago, when I type an application in the dash home, it says, no result found. I tried every application that I remember I had installed and everything is gone, except for those applications that are locked in the launcher and only the files and folders remained. I also try to click the Ubuntu Software but it buffer..I am a newbie in this..please give me a detailed solution on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `~/.local/share/zeitgeist` to `~/.local/share/zeitgeist.bak`.

Open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following command:

```
mv ~/.local/share/zeitgeist ~/.local/share/zeitgeist.bak
```

Then run:

```
kill -s TERM `pidof /usr/lib/unity-lens-applications/unity-applications-daemon`
```

Comment: where  can i move those things..:)
i'm sorry i really don't have an idea how..can you put it in a step by step process?..I do appreciate your answer very much..

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: please, will you show me how to move these in a step by step process..Honestly, I don't have any idea where to find the commands  above..please..

Comment: hi, this was the response..solis@solis:~$ mv ~/.local/share/zeitgeist ~/.local/share/zeitgeist.bak
solis@solis:~$ kill -s TERM pidof /usr/lib/unity-lens-applications/unity-applications-daemon
bash: kill: pidof: arguments must be process or job IDs
bash: kill: /usr/lib/unity-lens-applications/unity-applications-daemon: arguments must be process or job IDs....WHAT TO DO NEXT?

Comment: i tried but it didn't work...:(

Comment: There was a slight error. Try it now (with backticks).

Comment: what do  "backticks" means?

Comment: Backticks are the ones above the Tab key.

Comment: i would just like to clarify everything..after running those two commands up there, I will then enter first command the second time around?

Comment: You have to just run the two commands. Copy the first one (mv) and run it. Then the next one.

Comment: okay, then when that response above showed again I just need to enter the backticks?

Comment: Forget about backticks. Just copy and paste the two commands one by one and run them.

Comment: heloo..this is the result when I run the first command..mv: cannot stat `/home/solis/.local/share/zeitgeist': No such file or directory

Comment: and when I run the second command here is what it says..kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
bash: kill: pidof: arguments must be process or job IDs
bash: kill: /usr/lib/unity-lens-applications/unity-applications-daemonkill: arguments must be process or job IDs
bash: kill: -s: arguments must be process or job IDs
bash: kill: TERM: arguments must be process or job IDs
WHAT TO DO NEXT?

Comment: Try installing zeitgist - `sudo apt-get install zeitgist`, and run `ps -e | grep unity-applications` and post the output.

Comment: here is the result when i installed the zeitgist...."Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package zeitgist"...when i run the next command, nothing happens

Comment: `zeitgeist` is already installed in Ubuntu. It seems that something messed up with it. Now try reinstalling unity-lens-applications : `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-lens-application`, then reset unity - `unity --reset`. You might want to move to chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4725/discussion-between-mae-and-green7)

Comment: i'm sorry I guess I am not allowed to chat..anyway here is the response after re installing..Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package unity-lens-application

Comment: then as I reset unity here is the response..solis@solis:~$ unity --reset
WARNING: Unity currently default profile, so switching to metacity while resetting the values
Window manager warning: from event callback
Window manager warning: from event callback
Window manager warning: from event callback
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1a00004

Comment: compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x3600002

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1a0044f

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x3a0002e

Comment: Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing session options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done

Comment: Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing scale options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done

(compiz:3047): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
Initializing unityshell options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a0!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a3!

Comment: compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a6!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a9!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a9!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
WARN  2012-09-04 09:08:51 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop

Comment: ERROR 2012-09-04 09:08:56 unity.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Setting Update "main_menu_key"
Setting Update "run_key"
WARN  2012-09-04 09:10:15 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:182 Unable to connect to proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for com.canonical.Unity.Lens.A

Comment: [Moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4725/discussion-between-mae-and-green7). Future conversation there.